# Equivalent condition to integrability of a function

Tags: integration, measure-theory

> Let $f$ be a nonnegative Lebesgue measurable function on $[0,1]$. Prove that $f$ is >integrable on $[0,1]$ if and only if $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}m(\{x\in [0,1]; f(x)\geq k\}) < \infty$$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

The best I could do was use Chebyshev's inequality in the case that $f$ is integrable, but then the sum is bounded by $\int_0^1f\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ and the harmonic series diverges so that's not good. Any way to make this bound smaller? Or in general any other way to prove this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R_k = f^{-1}[k,k+1)$, $L_k = f^{-1}[k,\infty)$. Note that $L_k = \cup_{j=k}^\infty R_k$ and $m L_k = \sum_{j=k}^\infty m R_k$.

If $x\in R_k$, then $k \le f(x) < k+1$, so $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k 1_{R_k} \le f \le \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1) 1_{R_k} = 1 + \sum_{k=0}^\infty k 1_{R_k} $. Hence $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k 1_{R_k}$ is integrable **iff** $f$ is integrable.

We have $\int \sum_{k=0}^\infty k 1_{R_k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k \ m R_k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}  m R_k = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=j}^\infty m R_k = \sum_{j=0}^\infty m L_j$.

Hence $f$ is integrable **iff** $\sum_{k=0}^\infty m L_k < \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_k=\{x\in [0,1]: k-1\le f(x) <k\}$.

Clearly
$$
(k-1)\,m(A_k)\le\int_{A_k} f \,dx\le k\,m(A_k),
$$
and as
$$
\int_0^1  f \,dx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{A_k} f \,dx,
$$
combining the two we obtain
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k-1)\,m(A_k)\le\int_0^1  f \,dx\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty k\,m(A_k).\qquad (\star)
$$
Note that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k\,m(A_k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{\ell\ge k}m(A_{\ell})\right)
\quad\text{and}\quad
\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k-1)\,m(A_k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{\ell\ge k+1}m(A_{\ell})\right).
$$
Note also that if $E_k=\{x\in[0,1]:f(x)\ge k-1\}$, then $E_k=\bigcup_{\ell\ge k}A_\ell$ and
$$
m(E_k)=\sum_{\ell\ge k}m(A_\ell).
$$ 
Inequalities $(\star)$ now become
$$
\sum_{k=2}^\infty m(E_k)\le\int_0^1  f \,dx\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty m(E_k),
$$
which imply that $f$ is integrable iff $\sum_{k=1}^\infty m(E_k)<\infty$.